# Convert software RAID fileserver from Windows to Ubuntu

Tags: server, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, raid

I currently have a fileserver running on Windows 7 (it started as an old backup machine but has grown). It has 1 SSD for the OS, and 6 1TB HDDs, in 3 RAID 1 pairs. This was done via Windows' disk management. These drives are all formatted NTFS and have data on them.

My goal is install Ubuntu server on a new SSD, while maintaining all data on the HDDs.

Ubuntu has a built in partition/RAID configuration wizard during installation, however I'm unsure if this will cause any data loss.

What is the safest way to configure these drives in Ubuntu? Will it be necessary (or even highly recommended) to change the filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

What you will need first is to get the drivers of your RAID controller compatible for Ubuntu, I would run a LIVE USB Ubuntu and install the drivers there and test later if your 6 HDDs are visible, if you do, I would do the installation of the OS in your SSD drive (I would keep also just incase an image backup of your windows using Clonezilla)

Comment: I do not have a hardware RAID controller, I'm relying on software. Also, I have the other OS on a different SSD, so no worries there.